# DD-WRT + TekRADIUS: Having issues getting it to work

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, dd-wrt, wpa2

Has anyone else gotten it to work?

My setup:

```
Router: Netgear WNR3500v2
   WAN IP: y.y.y.y
   Radius: off
   Wireless Security:
      Security Mode: WPA2 Enterprise
      WPA Algorithms: AES
      Radius Auth Server Address: x.x.x.x
      Radius Auth Server Port: 1812
      Radius Auth Shared Secret: password
      Key Renewal Interval (in seconds): 3600

TekRadius Server:
   Users:
      test (username), User-Password (check): 1234, TLS-Server-Certificate (check) [created with TekCERT]
   Clients:
      Default (NAS), password (secret)
      y.y.y.y (NAS), password (secret)
   Settings:
      Service Parameters:
         Listen IP Address: x.x.x.x
         Authentication Port: 1812
         PEAP Inner Auth Method: EAP-MS-CHAP-v2

Computer Trying to Authenticate: Mac: 10.6.5
   Recognizes that the auth needs user/pass. 
   I type in test and 1234, nothing happens, it asks again.  
   Sometimes it "connects" says its authenticating, 
       and then disconnects, and then repeats.
```

Hardware setup:
TekRADIUS on Windows 7, plugged directly into the router.
Mac, trying to wirelessly authenticate with the netgear and the radius server.

Notes: I've been running wireshark while I've been trying to connect, and applied a filter of 'radius', and no packets have shown up.

In the TekRADIUS log, it shows nothing except when the server starts and stops, and these messages:

```
12/7/2010 5:06:34 AM - IP address configuration change has been detected
```

Which is weird, cause the IPs aren't changing.

Comment: i've done it with hostapd and freeradius on a cheap laptop but not with dd-wrt.

Comment: is there a gui front end for free radius? issue I had with it, when I looked at it briefly before, was that it was all command line... and there are just so many options, than a GUI to organize it all is kinda nice.

Comment: Also, I didn't look too much at the documentation for freeradius, but if it's easy to set up, I suppose I can give it another go.